# Finding $f'''(x)$ of $f(x)=\sin{\pi}x$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

> Finding $f'''(x)$ of $f(x)=\sin{\pi}x$.

First
$$f'(x)=\frac{d\sin{\pi}x}{d({\pi}x)}\frac{d({\pi}x)}{dx} ={\pi}\cos{\pi}x$$

Second
$$f''(x)=-{\pi^2}\sin{\pi}x$$

Third
$$f'''(x)= -{\pi^3}\cos {\pi}x$$

These are the steps the teacher has written down on the blackboard, I have trouble understanding "How it is solved".
Would you please provide the steps?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Statement

Comment: LaTeX tip: There are preexisting operators `\sin` and `\cos` for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. There is a quick reference guide [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \sin\pi x
\end{align*}
$$

Here, note that $\pi$ is a constant. So treat it like a coefficient of $x$. Progressively, what I will do is to:

- Isolate the coefficient since it is not involved in the differentiation
- Apply chain rule by differentiating the trigonometric function, followed by the function "inside" the trigo function - the $\pi x$. Note that $\frac{d}{dx}\begin{pmatrix}\pi x\end{pmatrix} = \pi$.

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \sin\pi x \\
f'(x) &= (\cos \pi x) \times \pi \space\space\tag{by chain rule}\\
&= \pi \cos \pi x
\\\\\\f''(x) &= \pi (-\sin \pi x)(\pi) \space\space\tag{by chain rule}\\
&= -\pi^2 \sin \pi x
\\\\\\f'''(x) &= \pi^2 (-\sin \pi x)(\pi) \space\space\tag{by chain rule}\\
&= -\pi^3 \cos \pi x
\end{align*}
$$
And that is how you do it.

**Comments**

I'll add comments here to address any of your future questions:

First, understand that $\cos$ is a trigonometric function. I would recommend you to write $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ as a **composite function**. I will do the easier one.

> If $p(x)$ = $\pi x$ and $q(x) = \sin x$, then $f(x) = q(p(x))$. To differentiate $f(x)$, apply **chain rule**.$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} q(\pi x) \times \frac{d}{dx} \pi x$$

Comment: Then, shouldn't be like this?
$$f'(x)={\pi}cos$$ why is ${\pi}x$ in the answer again. thx

Comment: Remember that cosine is a function.

Comment: @SbSangpi Because the chain rule indicates that if $$f(x)=g(h(x))$$ then $$f'(x) = g'(h(x))h'(x)$$

$\pi x$ is the $h(x)$.

Comment: @SbSangpi As a function, cosine needs an input, in other words $x$, or rather in this case $\pi x$. On its own, "$\cos$", is meaningless.